# How to configure @typescript-eslint rules

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm trying to convert to `@typescript-eslint` but the documentation seems sorely lacking. For example, I'm getting errors like this:

```
Line 58:  Expected a semicolon             @typescript-eslint/member-delimiter-style
```

I want to enforce no semicolons or commas. I found the documentation for that rule. https://github.com/bradzacher/eslint-plugin-typescript/blob/master/docs/rules/member-delimiter-style.md

But it doesn't seem to give any examples of how to configure it in a real eslint file! Anyone know how?

Comment: "I'm trying to convert to" --- JFYI, that project is not abandoned and is not going to be developed.

Comment: As your doc reference states, none is not an option for singleline because having no delimiter between members on a single line is a syntax error in TS.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using a .eslintrc.js configuration file you have to add this to the "rules" section:

```
"rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/member-delimiter-style": ["error", {
      multiline: {
        delimiter: 'none',    // 'none' or 'semi' or 'comma'
        requireLast: true,
      },
      singleline: {
        delimiter: 'semi',    // 'semi' or 'comma'
        requireLast: false,
      },
    }]
}
```

Worked for me for the "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type" parameter.
Options are from the [rules project site on github](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/src/rules/member-delimiter-style.ts)

Thanks to maxkoryukov for improving my original answer.

Comment: `singleline?: { delimiter?: 'semi' | 'comma'; }`, singleline.delimiter don't allow 'none'

Comment: You mention using a `.eslintrc.js` configuration file, but the snippet refers to a `.eslintrc` json file, right? Given that `"rules"` is between quotes.

Comment: You're right, it is json; but in an .eslintrc.js file. Here is an extract of the complete file: `module.exports = { "extends": ["plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"], "rules": { "@typescript-eslint/member-delimiter-style": ["error", { "multiline": {"delimiter":"none", "requireLast":true}, "singleline": {"delimiter":"semi", "requireLast":false}}]}};`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some example rules from a .eslintrc.js file from a VueJS Typescript project.

The two different rules relating to semi colons are for javascript/.vue files, and typescript/.ts files.

```
rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    quotes: [
      'error',
      'single'
    ],
    semi: [
      'error',
      'never'
    ],
    'vue/html-self-closing': [
      'error',
      {
        html: {
          void: 'any',
          normal: 'any',
          component: 'any'
        }
      }
    ],
    '@typescript-eslint/member-delimiter-style': [
      'error',
      {
        multiline: {
          delimiter: 'none',
          requireLast: true
        },
        singleline: {
          delimiter: 'semi',
          requireLast: false
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```