# set options for rule in .eslintrc.json

Tags: typescript, tslint

I'd like to use [this rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-inferrable-types.md) with the ignoreParameters option set to false. My eslint is configured with a `.eslintrc.json` file and I can't manage to find how to set the options for a rule in this file. I've looked the doc and googled, and I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56816619/how-to-configure-typescript-eslint-rules) but I couldn't find an example of how to set options for a rule with eslint and a `.eslintrc.json` file.

Here is my `.eslintrc.json` file before I try to add this rule (the rule is applied, but with default options instead of the options I want) :

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 0,
    "no-return-await": 2,
    "curly": 2
  }
}
```

and here is what I tried, always resulting in the rule not being applied anymore (with an error  `Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-inferable-types' was not found  @typescript-eslint/no-inferable-types`):

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 0,
    "no-return-await": 2,
    "curly": 2,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-inferable-types": [
      "error",
      {
        "ignoreParameters": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

or :

```
{
 "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
 "extends": [
   "react-app",
   "eslint:recommended",
   "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
   "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
   "plugin:prettier/recommended"
 ],
 "rules": {
   "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": 0,
   "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 0,
   "no-return-await": 2,
   "curly": 2,
   "@typescript-eslint/no-inferable-types": [
     2,
     {
       "ignoreParameters": true,
       "ignoreProperties": false
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So all things I tried were actually with the right syntax (I'll still let this question because I didn't find a clear resource with an example of a `.eslinrc.json` file with options, leading me to search problem at the wrong place).

My problem was I tried to change rule `no-inferrable-types` and I wrote the rule in my `.eslintrc.json` file `no-inferable-types` (with one "r" less).

My (working) `.eslintrc.json` is therefore this :

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 0,
    "no-return-await": 2,
    "curly": 2,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": [
      2,
      {
        "ignoreParameters": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but didn't work, i had to do: `"@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": "off"` instead. But thank you for your hint.